# Intl para formatar data no JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, data

Estou estudando o componente `Intl` do JavaScript e preciso formatar um campo data quem vem do banco de dados para o formato brasileiro.

Formato no MySQL: `2019-12-12`

E preciso transformá-lo em `12/12/2019`. O monetário eu já consigo fazer desta forma:

```
let value = 1,000.11

new Intl.NumberFormat('pt-BR', {
                        style: 'currency',
                        currency: 'BRL'
                       }).format(value);
```

Estou tentando fazer da mesma forma para converter os campos data mas não estou conseguindo.

```
let data = 2019-12-12
new Intl.DateTimeFormat('pt-BR').format(data);
```

Comment: Aparentemente você está passando o valor como *string* para o `format`, mas esse método espera um objeto `Date`.

Comment: `let data = 2019-12-12` - tem certeza que o código está assim? Porque isso na verdade é "2019 menos 12, menos 12", que resulta no número 1995...

Comment: é formato que está retornando do mysql `2019-12-14`

Comment: Mas neste caso deveria estar entre aspas: `let data = '2019-12-12'` - sem aspas, o JavaScript interpreta como números

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O método `Intl.DateTimeFormat.prototype.format` espera como parâmetro um objeto do tipo `Date`, então não deve passar uma *string* ([se realmente for uma *string* que está passando](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/427509/intl-para-formatar-data-no-javascript#comment829202_427509)).

```js
const date = new Date(2019, 11, 12);
const formated = (new Intl.DateTimeFormat('pt-br')).format(date);

console.log(formated);
```

Vale lembrar que no `Date` a contagem dos meses inicia em 0, por isso o mês de Dezembro foi indicado como 11.

A partir da *string* basta fazer `new Date('2019-12-12')`.

Comment: Só lembrando que o construtor que recebe números vai considerar "meia-noite no timezone do browser", enquanto o que recebe a string `'2019-12-12'` considera "meia-noite em UTC", o que exige uma pequena adaptação no `DateTimeFormat` - conforme [minha resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/427515/112052) abaixo. E +1 por ser mais rápido que eu :-)

Answer (score 7):

Primeiro você precisa entender uma coisa: **datas não têm formato**.

Uma data é apenas um conceito, que representa a ideia de um ponto específico na linha do tempo (ou em um sistema de calendário). No caso, `2019-12-12` e `12/12/2019` são apenas formas diferentes de se representar a mesma data (os mesmos valores do dia, mês e ano). Assim como `Dec 12th, 2019` ou `12 de dezembro de 2019`, são formatos diferentes, mas a data em si é a mesma.

Sendo assim, a data no MySQL não "está" em um formato. Internamente são guardados apenas os valores referentes à data. Quando você consulta os dados, aí a data é mostrada em algum formato, mas isso não significa necessariamente que ela está gravada naquele formato.

Então não está claro o que você tem. Se `2019-12-12` for uma string (ou seja, um texto representando a data), você pode criar um [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) e passá-lo para `Intl.DateTimeFormat`:

```js
let data = new Date('2019-12-12');
console.log(new Intl.DateTimeFormat('pt-BR', {timeZone: 'UTC'}).format(data));
```

[Segundo a documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Timestamp_string), quando a string está neste formato (ano-mês-dia - ou mais especificamente falando, no formato definido pela [norma ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)), o horário é setado para meia-noite e considera-se que a data/hora está em UTC.

Porém, o `DateTimeFormat` por padrão considera o fuso horário do browser, que pode não ser o mesmo que UTC e dar uma diferença na hora de formatar a data (por exemplo, meu browser usa o Horário de Brasília, e meia-noite do dia 12 em UTC corresponde às 21h do dia **11** no Horário de Brasília). Por isso eu informei o `timeZone: 'UTC'` no construtor.

[Na sua resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/427513/112052) funcionou porque você também passou os campos de horário, e neste caso o JavaScript considera o timezone do browser, por isso não é necessário informar que está em UTC.

Comment: Sempre aprendo algo novo com as suas repostas, é impressionante! :)

Answer (score 1):

Estou vendo aqui no [https://developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DateTimeFormat) e fiz a conversão para `new Date()` desta forma e funcionou

```js
let data = new Date('2019-12-14 00:00');
let print = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('pt-BR').format(data);

console.log(print);
```